# Adding AngularJS to existing ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm thinking about adding AngularJS to an existing app.
The app is an event management app with a dashboard action for each event. 
So we have something like http://localhost:3000/events/2/dashboard
We are trying to make the dashboard view more user friendly by adding AngularJS.

The goal is to implement a controller which will retrieve the event id to make calls to other services and populate the results into the view.

I've read about the $routeParams but in most of the case the examples were dealing with single page applications with their own templates.

Is there any clean way to just retrieve the event id param from the url?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure why you would consider bilding your app this way but no reason you can't pass routeParams as javascript object in script tag from your server controller/view. What do you plan to gain by using angular this way in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

By using the [angularUI router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) you can retrieve the event_id param from the url and you can also have nested views.

```
angular
  .module('paisApp')
  .config ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->

    $urlRouterProvider
      .otherwise("/")

    # Define 'app' states. The order of the state is important.

    $stateProvider
      .state "event_dashboard",
        parent: "default"
        url: "/events/:event_id/dashboard"
        views:
          "":
            controller: "EventsController"
            templateUrl: "/assets/events/dashboard.html.erb"
```

Now in your events controller you can use the following to access the event_id

```
$stateParams['event_id']
```

Comment: I got impression OP didn't want to use angular routing but load each server side page

Comment: @charlietfl Yes right. for some reason I can't move my dashboard template to the assets directory. Instead of having angular render the view, I just need a way to alter the server-side view with some content coming from my angular controller